# Tomcat error message: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: listeners.ContextListener/ SessionListener / websocket.drawboard.DrawboardContextListener

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, tomcat8

I am trying to deploy an application in TOMCAT but facing this unusual error (I mean never encountered this before).

```
27-Jul-2015 12:41:49.870 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class websocket.drawboard.DrawboardContextListener
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: websocket.drawboard.DrawboardContextListener

27-Jul-2015 12:41:49.870 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
27-Jul-2015 12:45:35.141 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class listeners.ContextListener
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: listeners.ContextListener

27-Jul-2015 12:45:35.146 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class listeners.SessionListener
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: listeners.SessionListener
```

The application is spring based. The web.xml looks like this:

```
<!--Application Context-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!--Dispatcher Servlet-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

The pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<!--Spring Dependencies-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!--Hibernate Dependencies-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.0.RELEASE</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>

            <!--JUnit Test Dependency-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>

            <!--Log4J-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>

            <!--MySQL Dependencies-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.35</version>
            </dependency>

            <!--JSON Conversion Dependency-->
            <dependency>  
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>  
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>  
                <version>1.9.12</version>  
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.21</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
```

I am wondering what is the problem here. I have previously deployed the application in TOMCAT and didn't get any error message. I have already looked other posts and forums but couldn't solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well that's a different scenario after deployment. I can't even deploy the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was the problem but after I downloaded the Tomcat VERSION 8.0.24 then I never got the problem back. The problem as with VERSION 8.0.21